# ifdef-like behavior in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab

Is there a way of creating pieces of code inside a `.m` file that are parsed once at compile time in MATLAB?

For example, assume you have a piece of code that is modal and will be executed several times, but it will always use the same mode. However, for portability and easiness of reading the code, I will prefer to have all the different modes in the same file. Something in the lines of

```
if mode==1
  % code of mode 1
elseif mode==2
  % code of mode 2
elseif mode==3
  % code of mode 3
end
```

However, if this file is executed thousand times I have to execute this conditional thousand times. But for each run I will set the mode and don't change it.

Therefore, I was thinking if MATLAB have something in the lines of a `#ifdef` like C in which I can strip out all the other parts that won't be using in the execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could solve your problem elegantly using a [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Think setting a function handle in your code - or even making strategy objects if you are into object oriented.

Comment: +1 you would create a `select_implementation` function that returns a function handle to one of the possible implementations `@func1, @func2, ..` (each in a separate M-file). This would be called once, and the returned function handle would be passed along to the actual call that performs the iterations: `fh = select_implementation(..); for i=1:1e5, out(i) = my_alg(fh, i, ...); end`

Comment: If you want to do this with all the code in the same file - which was the OP's original request - I suspect that the overhead of a function (the main function of the module) calling another function (given by the handle) would defeat the purpose of the question; would you care to comment? I agree that swapping file handles as a solution is elegant, but I am unconvinced about the efficiency gain over the sequential `if` or `switch`.

Comment: @Floris: sorry for the late reply (didnt get notified without the "at username" thing). When MATLAB resolves function calls subfunctions (all in one file) have a higher precedence than extrinsic functions, so might execute a tiny bit faster. Inlined code would be even faster. Although I dont think efficiency would matter much here as much as readability and good code organization, any performance gain here would be tiny if any. Dont you think so?

Comment: @arnro - I agree. I advocate clean code (maintainable, less likely to be buggy) over "fast but obscure" any day; and these variations will have little speed difference, most likely.

Answer (score 3):

Because Matlab uses a just in time compiler, what you are proposing might lead to the unintended consequence that a piece of code was compiled for one "mode", then is left in memory. The next time you run it (if you didn't close matlab and didn't explicitly "forget" about the function), you will still be using it in this mode - even if you intended to change it. I don't think it can be done, and it's a good thing...

If you need speed, there are much better ways to achieve it than removing a `switch` statement - which would be my preferred alternative to yours (again, for readability if nothing else).

```
switch (mode)
  case 1:
    % code of mode 1
  case 2:
    % code of mode 2
  case 3: 
    % code of mode 3
  otherwise:
    % always trap the unexpected input!!!
end
```

Finally - you could of course create a `mex` file which was conditionally compiled with the right options. This would actually allow you to do exactly what you were asking for, and it would have the added advantage of being much faster than native Matlab code. You can pass a #define to the `mex` command with the `-D` switch (see http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html) - example

```
mex -DmyMode=2
```

There is a ton of material on creating mex files on the web. I assume you can find it.